# OSMNX KeyError when trying to compute edge_centrality on a graph composition

Tags: openstreetmap, python-3, graph, networkx, osmnx

#### Context:

I am trying to merge several different graphs (some sharing nodes with others) downloaded from [openstreetmap](https://openstreetmap.org) using [omsmx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx).

While storing these different graphs in a list, I use the [`nx.compose_all()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.all.compose_all.html) method from [networkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/) to combine them into a single graph:

`G_unique = nx.compose_all(Graphs_list)`

Then I want to compute [edge centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closeness_centrality) on the graph edges using networkX's [`nx.closeness_centrality()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.closeness_centrality.html) function on its [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) (by prior using [`nx.line_graph()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.line.line_graph.html) function of the [primal graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primal_graph)):

```
e_c = nx.closeness_centrality(nx.line_graph(G_unique))
```

All this is also well described by Geoff Boeing in its tutorial: [08-example-line-graph.ipynb](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/08-example-line-graph.ipynb) on github.

#### The error:

But while trying to retrieve the value of that centrality, I always encounter the same error:

```
[e_c[edge + (0,)] for edge in G_unique.edges()]
```

Which returns a `KeyError`:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-6410c27e0882> in <module>
----> 1 [e_c[edge + (0,)] for edge in G_unique.edges()]

<ipython-input-92-6410c27e0882> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [e_c[edge + (0,)] for edge in G_unique.edges()]

KeyError: (292494260, 244429342, 0)
```

As if this edge had never been found...

Precision: the same problem appears if I use [`nx.compose()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.compose.html) in a `for` loop on all the graphs composing the list `Graphs_list`.

#### Question:

How can I solve this problem?

#### Environment:

- Ubuntu 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)
- numpy 1.17.4
- networkx 2.4
- osmnx 0.10

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete reproducible code snippet so we can reproduce your error and answer your question.